# Use a particular set of where clauses depending on the comparision of 2 cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way to use a particular set of where clauses depending on the comparison of 2 cells in a table. So that if the active date is less then the submit date the count will be based off the submit date where clause otherwise the opposite is done. I have looked at trying to use a CASE but couldn't figure out how to utilise it in such a situation. The reason I am trying to do this in SQL and not code is because fast response speed is required. Thanks

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Work_Order_ID) AS OutSLA
FROM
    WOI_WorkOrder
WHERE
    ASGRP IN ( 'WOIQUE)
AND
    (Status = 'Assigned' OR Status = 'Pending' OR Status = 'In Progress')
AND
    IF(Active_Date < Submit_Date)
        Submit_Date < '2014-07-28 00:00:00'
    ELSE
      Active_Date < '2014-07-28 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(case when Active_Date < Submit_Date and Submit_Date < '2014-07-28' then 1
             when Active_Date >= Submit_Date and Active_Date < '2014-07-28' then 1
        end) AS OutSLA
FROM
    WOI_WorkOrder
WHERE
    ASGRP IN ('WOIQUE')
AND
    Status = 'Assigned' OR Status = 'Pending' OR Status = 'In Progress'
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers are correct, the `WHERE` clauses doesn't have to be this difficult. Because if you think about your `IF` statement, `Active_Date` and `Submit_Date` will both always be less than `2014-07-28`.
So the `WHERE` clause will become
    `Active_Date < '2014-07-28' AND Submit_Date < '2014-04-28'` is the same.

This will not only improve readability, but also query performance.
Your whole query will then look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Work_Order_ID) as OutSLA
FROM WOI_WorkOrder
WHERE ASGRP IN ('WOIQUE')
 AND Status IN ('Assigned', 'Pending', 'In Progress')
 AND Submit_Date < '2014-07-28'
 AND Active_Date < '2014-07-28';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this just using the `where` clause (which seems to be the intention of the original query):

```
SELECT COUNT(Work_Order_ID) as OutSLA
FROM WOI_WorkOrder
WHERE ASGRP IN ('WOIQUE') AND
      Status IN ('Assigned', 'Pending', 'In Progress') AND
      (Active_Date < Submit_Date and Submit_Date < '2014-07-28' or
       Active_Date >= Submit_Date and Active_Date < '2014-07-28'
      );
```

Note that I also replaced the list of `or` clauses with `in`.  This is easier to write and read.